# How to add task list to existing DAG

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to automate the creation of batch pipelines from backend mySQLL to BiqQuery and I've ran into issue with my script.

It initialises a DAG with it's own class (DagCreator) and then passes it as a instance variable in my MySQLBatchPipelines class.

The tasks and the order of the tasks are contained in methods inside my MySQLBatchPipelines instance.

How would I add those tasks and the tasks list to my existing DAG?

Here's some example code so you understand my query:

```
class DagCreator:

    def __init__(
        self,
        dag_id,
        start_date,
        time_delay: int
    ):
        self.dag_id = dag_id,
        self.start_date = start_date,
        self.time_delay = time_delay

        print(self.dag_id)

    def DagToReturn(self):
        args = {
            'owner': 'Data Lake',
            'depends_on_past': True,
            'start_date': self.start_date,
            'email_on_failure': False,
            'email_on_retry': False,
            'on_failure_callback': 'failed_dag_slack_alert',
            'retries': 0,
            'max_active_runs': 1,
            'max_file_size': int(50e6)
        }
        dag_to_return = DAG(
            dag_id=f'{self.dag_id}_batch',
            schedule_interval=f'{self.time_delay} * * *',
            concurrency=4,
            default_args=args
        )
        return dag_to_return

dag = DagCreator('table_name', dt.datetime(2022, 1, 15), 7)
dag_returned = dag.DagToReturn()
dag_returned
```

This is the second class and it's methods:

```
class MySQLBatchPipeline:
    '''
    Class to generate MySQL batch pipelines that store CSV's 
    in GCS then import them into BigQuery
    '''
    export_format='CSV' 

    def __init__(
        self,
        dag,
    ....

    # lots of methods that return tasks like these
    def uk_source_table_extract_task(self):
        uk_source_table_extract_task = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            sql=self.queries['new_rows_batch_query'], # <--- needs testing
            bucket=self.gcs_bucket,
            filename=self.extract_gcs_path,
            approx_max_file_size_bytes=MAX_FILE_SIZE, # <-- is max_file_size necc? is in dag arg's is it necc here
            mysql_conn_id=self.mysql_connection_id,
            export_format=self.export_format,
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id=self.gcs_connection_id,
            params={
                'export_format': self.export_format,
                'country': 'uk',
                'time_delay': self.time_delay
            },
            task_id='uk_source_table_extract_task',
            dag=self.dag
      return uk_expected_stg_row_count_extract_task


    # this the the workflow I want to add to the existing DAG I've passed a instance attribute
        def uk_workflow(self):
            uk_source_table_extract_task.set_downstream(
                [
                    uk_table_name_load_task,
                    uk_truncate_table_name_staging_task,
                    uk_expected_stg_row_count_extract_task
                ]
            )
            uk_truncate_table_name_staging_task.set_downstream(
            uk_table_name_load_task
            # etc etc until the final task
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class `MySQLBatchPipeline` into the class `DagCreator`, so you can use the task into the main class where the DAGs are.

You can see this example to import the class of the task.

```
from includes.foo_bar_tasks import build_foo_task, build_bar_task
from includes.xyzzy_taskgroup import build_xyzzy_taskgroup
```

Here is an example to call the tasks.

```
   # logical chunk of tasks
   foo_task = build_foo_task(dag=dag)
   bar_task = build_bar_task(dag=dag)
```

The sequence of the task.

```
# taskgroup
xyzzy_taskgroup = build_xyzzy_taskgroup(dag=dag)
foo_task >> bar_task >> xyzzy_taskgroup
```

You can see this code [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/break-up-a-big-airflow-dag-into-multiple-files-5262accf6713).

Here is documentation about the [task in Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html#).

**Airflow 1.10.10**

You need to disable this parameter [DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/concepts.html#dags) in the configuration flag. This is because Airflow only searches Python files that contain Airflow and DAG words by default.

You can see this example:

**dynamic_dags.py:**

```
def generate_dag(name):
    with DAG(
        /*
    Code
*/
    ) as dag:
        dummy_task=DummyOperator(
          /*
    Code
*/
        )
    return dag
```

Another file is importing the dags from a separate file:

**load_dags.py:**

```
from dynamic_dag import generate_dag
globals()["Dynamic_DAG_A"] = generate_dag('A')
```

Another option is to use [airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html#module-airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor). This module waits for a different task or DAG to complete for a specific execution date. You can see this [code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html#ExternalTaskMarker.template_fields).

Comment: This is great but I'm working on Airflow 1.10.10. Is there an alternative workaround for this version of Airflow?

Comment: @ma8701 I updated my answer.